# Kohana Error when trying to enter controller (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 324)

Tags: php, kohana

I keep recieving this error in Kohana when trying to access

http://example.com/dailysales

When i'm on production. locally it works fine..
also when trying to enter Notifications on productions it works..
and my bootstrap is the same..

this is my bootstrap routes

```
Route::set('notifications', '(<controller>)(/<action>)', array('controller' => 'notifications|dailysales', 'action' => 'index|send'))
->defaults(array('controller' => 'notifications', 'action' => 'index'));


Route::set('sales', 'sales(/<action>)', array('action' => 'index|export'))
->defaults(array('controller' => 'sales', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: Does this problem appear in a different browsers? Or is it just a Chrome bug (possible http://www.roezer.com/fixing-chrome-bug-error-324-neterr_empty_response/)?

Answer (score 1):

First, the first route shouldn't have 2 optional parameters. Second, put some parenthesis in your pcre regex. Third, more specific routes should always go first:

```php
Route::set('sales', 'sales(/<action>)', array('action' => '(index|export)'))
->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'sales', 
  'action' => 'index'
));

Route::set('notifications', '<controller>(/<action>)', array(
   'controller' => '(notifications|dailysales)', 
   'action' => '(index|send)'
))
->defaults(array(
   'controller' => 'notifications', 
   'action' => 'index'
));
```

And lastly, check if your `Kohana::$environment` is being set properly and if the 'development' have any differences from the 'production' (different configs for each environment). The last thing "to blame" would be PHP version.